# Memory ever increasing with python+ctypes+scipy nquad

Tags: python-3.x, scipy, ctypes

So i'm writing a some integration code and to speed up it was trying out using ctypes. But the memory used by the code increases constantly eventually running out (confirmed via watching top and the eventual killing of my script). Here's a what i have got so far:

```
import numpy as np
import scipy.integrate as integrate
import ctypes 

lib=ctypes.CDLL('/path/to/testIntDist.so')

cFunc=lib.intBin
cFunc.restype=ctypes.c_double
cFunc.argtypes=(ctypes.c_int,ctypes.c_double)

def pyFunc(x1,x2,x3):
    x=(x1**x2)*np.log10(x3)
    return x

def intFunc(x1min,x1max,x2min,x2max,x3min,x3max):
    x=integrate.nquad(cFunc,[[float(x1min),float(x1max)],[float(x2min),float(x2max)],[float(x3min),float(x3max)]])[0]
    return x

line='1.0 1 1 1 1 0.1 0.111178446136 0.1 0.111178446136 3.0 3.1299027994'

for i in range(1,50000):
    x=list(line.split())
    res=intFunc(x[5],x[6],x[7],x[8],x[9],x[10])
    print(res)
```

Where testIntDist.c is:

```
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <math.h>

double intBin(int n, double args[n]){
    double x1,x2,x3;
    x1=args[0];
    x2=args[1];
    x3=args[2];
    return pow(x1,x2)*log10(x3);
}
```

Compiled with:

```
gcc -O2 -shared -fPIC -o testIntDist.so testIntDist.c -lm
```

Code versions:

```
gcc 4.6.3
python 3.2.3
scipy 0.15.1
```

If i switch from cFunc to pyFunc (ie a python version of the function) the memory usage stays constant during the run. Is there something i should be doing after a call to cFunc to free memory?

Adding gc.collect() after the print statement to force garbage collection, doesn't help. And running with memory_profiler

```
Line #    Mem usage    Increment   Line Contents
================================================
    16   36.836 MiB    0.000 MiB   @profile
    17                             def intFunc(x1min,x1max,x2min,x2max,x3min,x3max):
    18   36.836 MiB    0.000 MiB    x=integrate.nquad(cFunc,[[float(x1min),float(x1max)],[float(x2min),float(x2max)],[float(x3min),float(x3max)]])[0]
    19   36.836 MiB    0.000 MiB    return x
```

Doesn't seem to tell me much.

Thanks.

Comment: You define `cFunc`, `intBin`, as taking an `int` and array pointer, but `pyFunc` takes 3 ints.  One isn't a dropin replacement for the other.  I don't see anything that would set the first `intBin` argument to `3`.

Comment: [`integrate.nquad`](http://docs.scipy.org/doc/scipy/reference/generated/scipy.integrate.nquad.html) doesn't actually use ctypes to call the function. It only uses ctypes to get the address. If there's a memory leak here, it could be in [`quadpack_qagse`](https://github.com/scipy/scipy/blob/master/scipy/integrate/__quadpack.h#L240), or [`init_c_multivariate`](https://github.com/scipy/scipy/blob/master/scipy/integrate/quadpack.h#L144) / `restore_c_multivariate`.